# Why do most computer components get power through the motherboard?

Tags: power-supply, cpu, motherboard

I understand that most of the components of the computer needs power to operate, and they get power from the motherboard.

Why must the computer components indirectly get power from the motherboard but not directly from the PSU (power supply unit)?

Comment: There is no must - high end GPUs use mainly the PSU directly, some analog cards have direct connection. But it's quite convenient not having to wire all cards to the PSU directly (less wires hanging around) and there could be damage if the Mainboard applies a voltage but the card was not connected to the PSU....

Comment: Less cabling = lower cost.

Comment: You'd need an awful lot of wires and connectors to power every component directly from the PSU.

Comment: By "component", do you mean chips soldered to the motherboard, or peripherals such as hard disks?

Comment: Which components specifically are you thinking about? Wi-Fi cards?

Comment: Most of the aerospace systems power their assemblies through backplanes (like motherboards).  Power supplies, receivers, digital processors, all plug into a backplane which distributes the needed voltages to the assemblies.  Only place we may deviate from that approach is where high current - many hundreds of amps - are involved.

Comment: I can only think of two kinds of components in my computer which *don't* get power directly from the PSU: those are the CPU, and lowish-power PCIe devices (not graphics cards).

Comment: @user253751 and fans, and ssds, usb breakouts, rgb lights, buzzers, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> most of the components of the computer needs power to operate

**All** of them need power.

> not directly from the PSU (power supply unit)?

Depends. GPUs and HDDs/SSDs get their supplies directly from the PSU. But motherboard (MoBo) acts partly as a distribution network as well for the rest of the components (including electromechanicals).

There are tens of different components in a computer, and they need different voltage levels from 1V to 12V. And some of these voltages need to be changed dynamically. A CPU is a good example to need of dynamic supply voltage: The voltage can be anything between, say, 1V and 1.2V during normal operation.

There are converters on the MoBo to generate required voltages. It's even better because providing supply at point of load has lots of advantages.

So, in terms of practicality and cost effectiveness, providing common voltages from PSU to MoBo is the best option.